# How to create efficient HttpClient for multiple clients using HttpClientFactory?

Tags: c#, .net-core, httpclientfactory

This is a best practice question.

I am using `HttpClientFactory` to create `HttpClient`. There is a scenario where I might end up doing similar for other client integration. So rather than duplicate logic in two places, I want to keep it centralized.

But I do not know if having common place for Client would be good practice in case of higher volume of calls or not. This is where I need some help on how to scale and do not keep duplicate code if possible. As you can see in below code, `ApiClientOne` and `ApiClientTwo` has same private function for request. What I want is, have the centralized place for that and keep N clients calling that.

- If I move `async Task<T> Request<T>(HttpMethod method, string endpoint, object payload = null)` to common place and have N clients call it then, would it scale?
- Is there a better way to achieve the desired result?
- Or should I keep these separate? (the way it is now)

**Code:**

Program.cs

```
.ConfigureServices((_, services) =>
{
    services.AddApiClientOne(config);
    services.AddApiClientTwo(config);
})
```

ServiceContainer.cs

```
namespace Configuration
{
    [ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
    public static class ServiceContainer
    {
        public static void AddApiClientTwo(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            services.AddHttpClient<IApiClientTwo, ApiClientTwo>((serviceProvider, httpClient) =>
            {
                httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(configuration.GetSettings("Services:ApiClientTwo:BaseUrl", ""));
                httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");

                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer",
                    serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IInternalAuthClient>().GetTokenAsync()
                        .GetAwaiter().GetResult());
            });
        }

        public static void AddApiClientOne(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            services.AddHttpClient<IApiClientOne, ApiClientOne>("ApiClientOne", options =>
            {
                options.BaseAddress = new Uri(configuration.GetSettings("Services:ClientOne:BaseUrl", string.Empty, false));
                options.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("clientId", configuration[Configurations.ClientOneClientId]);
                options.SetBasicAuthentication(configuration[Configurations.ClientOneUsername],
                    configuration[Configurations.ClientOnePassword]);
            });
            
        }

     }
}
```

ApiCleintOne.cs

```
namespace Clients.ApiClientOne;

public class ApiClientOne : IApiClientOne
{
    private readonly ILogger<ApiClientOne> _logger;
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
    private Lazy<JsonSerializerOptions> _settings;
    
    public ApiClientOne(HttpClient httpClient, ILogger<ApiClientOne> logger)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
        _logger = logger;
        _settings = new Lazy<JsonSerializerOptions>(CreateSerializerSettings);
    }
    
    public async Task<GetSomethingResponse> GetSomething(string value)
    {
        var response = await Request<GetSomethingResponse>(HttpMethod.Get, $"/something/{value}");
        return response;
    }
    
    private JsonSerializerOptions CreateSerializerSettings()
    {
        var settings = new JsonSerializerOptions
        {
            PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase
        };
        return settings;
    }

    private async Task<T> Request<T>(HttpMethod method, string endpoint, object payload = null)
    {
        var client = _httpClient;
        var disposeClient = false;

        using var request = new HttpRequestMessage();
        var content_ = new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(payload, _settings.Value));
        content_.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");
        request.Content = content_;
        request.Method = method;
        request.Headers.Accept.Add(MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue.Parse("application/json"));
        request.RequestUri = new Uri(endpoint, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

        var response = await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).ConfigureAwait(false);
        var disposeResponse_ = true;
        
        try
        {
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var headers =
                Enumerable.ToDictionary(response.Headers, h_ => h_.Key, h_ => h_.Value);
            if (response.Content != null && response.Content.Headers != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in response.Content.Headers)
                    headers[item.Key] = item.Value;
            }

            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var errorMessage = $"some error.";
                _logger.Error($"{errorMessage} {{ @content }}", args: new object[] {content});
                throw new HttpRequestException($"{errorMessage} - {content}", null, response.StatusCode);
            }

            return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(content);
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException ex) when (ex.StatusCode.HasValue && 500 <= (int) ex.StatusCode &&
                                              (int) ex.StatusCode < 600)
        {
            throw new DependencyFailureApiException(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (disposeResponse_)
            {
                response.Dispose();
                client.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ApiClientTwo.cs

```
namespace Clients.ApiClientTwo;

public class ApiClientTwo : IApiClientTwo
{
    private readonly ILogger<ApiClientTwo> _logger;
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
    private Lazy<JsonSerializerOptions> _settings;
    
    public ApiClientTwo(HttpClient httpClient, ILogger<ApiClientTwo> logger)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
        _logger = logger;
        _settings = new Lazy<JsonSerializerOptions>(CreateSerializerSettings);
    }
    
    public async Task<PostSomethingResponse> PostSomething(MyModel value)
    {
        var response = await Request<PostSomethingResponse>(HttpMethod.Post, $"/postSomething", value);
        return response;
    }
    
    private JsonSerializerOptions CreateSerializerSettings()
    {
        var settings = new JsonSerializerOptions
        {
            PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase
        };
        return settings;
    }

    private async Task<T> Request<T>(HttpMethod method, string endpoint, object payload = null)
    {
        var client = _httpClient;
        var disposeClient = false;

        using var request = new HttpRequestMessage();
        var content_ = new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(payload, _settings.Value));
        content_.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");
        request.Content = content_;
        request.Method = method;
        request.Headers.Accept.Add(MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue.Parse("application/json"));
        request.RequestUri = new Uri(endpoint, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

        var response = await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).ConfigureAwait(false);
        var disposeResponse_ = true;

        try
        {
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var headers =
                Enumerable.ToDictionary(response.Headers, h_ => h_.Key, h_ => h_.Value);
            if (response.Content != null && response.Content.Headers != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in response.Content.Headers)
                    headers[item.Key] = item.Value;
            }

            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var errorMessage = $"some error.";
                _logger.Error($"{errorMessage} {{ @content }}", args: new object[] { content });
                throw new HttpRequestException($"{errorMessage} - {content}", null, response.StatusCode);
            }

            return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(content);
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException ex) when (ex.StatusCode.HasValue && 500 <= (int)ex.StatusCode &&
                                              (int)ex.StatusCode < 600)
        {
            throw new DependencyFailureApiException(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (disposeResponse_)
            {
                response.Dispose();
                client.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When I've done this, I've followed the recommendations in the Microsoft docs for _named_ clients using an injected `IHttpClientFactory`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can factor out this common method into a `static` helper type, possibly as an extension method on `HttpClient`. This will not affect scalability at all.

Example extension method:

```
static class MyHttpClientExtensions
{
    public static async Task<T> MyRequestAsync<T>(this HttpClient client, HttpMethod method, string endpoint, object payload = null)
    {
        var disposeClient = false;

        using var request = new HttpRequestMessage();
        var content_ = new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(payload, _settings.Value));
        content_.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");
        request.Content = content_;
        request.Method = method;
        request.Headers.Accept.Add(MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue.Parse("application/json"));
        request.RequestUri = new Uri(endpoint, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

        var response = await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).ConfigureAwait(false);
        var disposeResponse_ = true;

        try
        {
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var headers =
                Enumerable.ToDictionary(response.Headers, h_ => h_.Key, h_ => h_.Value);
            if (response.Content != null && response.Content.Headers != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in response.Content.Headers)
                    headers[item.Key] = item.Value;
            }

            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var errorMessage = $"some error.";
                _logger.Error($"{errorMessage} {{ @content }}", args: new object[] { content });
                throw new HttpRequestException($"{errorMessage} - {content}", null, response.StatusCode);
            }

            return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(content);
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException ex) when (ex.StatusCode.HasValue && 500 <= (int)ex.StatusCode &&
                                              (int)ex.StatusCode < 600)
        {
            throw new DependencyFailureApiException(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (disposeResponse_)
            {
                response.Dispose();
                client.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With the extension method above, both your consumers can look like this:

```
public async Task<GetSomethingResponse> GetSomething(string value)
{
    var response = await _httpClient.MyRequestAsync<GetSomethingResponse>(HttpMethod.Get, $"/something/{value}");
    return response;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. I'll play with this approach and see how it goes. I'll add my findings here.

Comment: So far this is working as expected. Thank you.